# match query in hibernate for two characters

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate with mysql
I have a keyword in my java for which i need to retrieve record from MySQL

```
    Restrictions.like("resume Text", keyword, Match Mode.ANYWHERE));
```

when i send keyword as **test**  it works ,when i send keyword as **sample** it works BUT when i send keyword as **test,sample** it fails,don't return any result.

Any Solution

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bohemian is spot on but if you would have more than 2 or-clauses then you're probably better of using Disjunction (or) or Conjunction (and):

```
        Disjunction orClause = Restrictions.disjunction();
        orClause.add(Restrictions.like("resume Text", "test", Match Mode.ANYWHERE));
        orClause.add(Restrictions.like("resume Text", "test", Match Mode.ANYWHERE));
        orClause.add(...)
        criteria.add(orClause);
```

Comment: thanks , you are right but what if a user enters sample,test  in one keyword ,or even  test,sample,test,test2 in search box , then how will i distribute one keyword into 4 and use 4 different clauses.

Comment: easy, put `orClause.add(...)` in a for-loop for each comma separated value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass in multiple values to the single-valued `value` parameter of [like](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#like%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode%29).

Try using [Restrictions.or](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#or%28org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion,%20org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion%29) to construct you logic, like this:

```
Restrictions.or(
    Restrictions.like("resume Text", "test", Match Mode.ANYWHERE),
    Restrictions.like("resume Text", "sample", Match Mode.ANYWHERE)
);
```

Or use [Restrictions.and](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#and%28org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion,%20org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion%29) instead, depending on the matching logic you are trying to achieve